# Are code freezes irrelevant with Git?

Tags: git, svn

In the context of Git's advantages (objective) over SVN, does the easier merging/branching features of Git make code freezing irrelevant when using Git (or equivalent)?  Did the concept of code freezing come about because merging later is so hard?

I realize that this might be a subjective question but I really want to know if the phrase "code freeze" is antiquated or indicative of a project that isn't branching and merging easily.  If you could branch and merge automatically, would you ever code freeze?  I don't think you would because you could topic/feature branch locally and continue development knowing that merging would be easy.

Comment: Code freeze can be for political reasons too.  Many corporations go into code freeze around the time to announce financial results.  Both to prevent an accidentally-introduced bug in the financial systems from messing up financial results, but also to try to prevent some large-scale system problem (say, the ordering system going down) from generating bad press around financial results time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true, that you can continue doing feature and "risky" development, easy branching and merging does in no way obsolete code freezes.

You either freeze the release branch and hope people will still work on it or freeze master and hope more people will help with the final release blockers' removal and polishing (they're practically forced if they don't know the SCM well).

Apart from release code quality, code freezes are crucial for translators, since a code freeze is usually accompanied by a string freeze, at which point it finally makes sense to fix up translations completely.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with how easy it is to merge the changes. The point of a freeze is to stop development on a stable release. On a freeze you would only be fixing bugs. You do not want code automatically merged because it could have untested code and introduce bugs. You would typically tag a freeze and develop in a trunk/branch until your next release.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what "code freezing" means.

If you means everybody switch to bug squishing mode. -- why not? bugs always need some love.

If you means everybody do nothing and wait for the QA team. -- no this is irrelevant with git.